# Find the value of $\frac{4x}{y+1} + \frac{16y}{z+1} + \frac{64z}{x+1}$

Tags: contest-math, real-numbers, fractions

> Let $x,y,z$ be positive real numbers such that $x+y+z = 1$ and $xy+yz+zx = \frac{1}{3}$. Find the vlaue of $$\frac{4x}{y+1} + \frac{16y}{z+1} + \frac{64z}{x+1}.$$

So far using the fact that $(x+y+z)^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2 + 2(xy+yz+zx)$, I was able to get $x^2+y^2+z^2 = \frac{1}{3}$. Then I tried finding the common denominator of $\frac{4x}{y+1} + \frac{16y}{z+1} + \frac{64z}{x+1}$, which got very messy quickly and I think there's a nicer way to do this problem, but for now I am stuck.

Comment: Just a comment: there is no need to assume that $x,y,z>0$.  The three variables merely need to be real numbers.  The only $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ satisfying $x+y+z=1$ and $xy+yz+zx=\frac13$ is $\left(\frac13,\frac13,\frac13\right)$.  Lord Shark the Unknown's proof verifies this claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that $x=y=z=1/3$.

Too see this consider
$$0=(x+y+z)^2-3(xy+xz+yz)=\frac{(x-y)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2}{2}.$$